# Custom subarray of a multidimensional array

Tags: matlab, sampling

I have an array `A` which has a size `[N1 N2 N3 3 3]`. Array `A` can be considered as a rectangular box in three dimensions that for each of its element, an array of size `[3 3]` is defined, and here I call it `B`. In other words, `B` with size `[3 3]` is defined for each point in the domain.

I am trying to subdivide the rectangular box into small cubes of size `d×d×d`, where `d` is an even number. Also, there should be `50%` overlap between adjacent cubes and . For example, let's say:

```
A; % size(A) = [14 16 20 3 3];
d = 4;
```

With the above example, the sampling will be as follows. The cubes along with with first dimension of `A`, i.e., `1:14` will include the following elements of `A`:

```
cube1: 1, 2, 3, 4
cube2: 3, 4, 5, 6
cube3: 5, 6, 7, 8
cube4: 7, 8, 9, 10
cube5: 9, 10,11,12
cube6: 11,12,13,14
```

along the second dimension of `A`, i.e., `1:16`, we have:

```
cube1: 1, 2, 3, 4
cube2: 3, 4, 5, 6
cube3: 5, 6, 7, 8
cube4: 7, 8, 9, 10
cube5: 9, 10,11,12
cube6: 11,12,13,14
cube7: 13,14,15,16
```

And finally along the third dimension of `A`, i.e., `1:20`:

```
cube1: 1, 2, 3, 4
cube2: 3, 4, 5, 6
cube3: 5, 6, 7, 8
cube4: 7, 8, 9, 10
cube5: 9, 10,11,12
cube6: 11,12,13,14
cube7: 13,14,15,16
cube8: 15,16,17,18
cube9: 17,18,19,20
```

Now `Anew` will have a size `[6 7 9 3 3]` and the value at each of its element will be the summation of each element of `B` over all the element of `A` that are in each cube. For example, `Anew(1, 4, 9, 1, 1)` is actually:

```
A(elements of cube1, elements of cube4, elements of cube9, 1, 1)
```

or in other words, `A(1:4, 7:10, 17:20)`. Therefore:

```
Anew(1, 4, 9, 1, 1) = 0;
for i = 1:4           % cube1 along with first dimension uses 1, 2, 3, 4
    for j = 7:10      % cube4 along with the second dimension uses 7, 8, 9, 10
        for k = 17:20 % cube9 along with the third dimension uses 17, 18, 19, 20
            Anew(1, 4, 9, 1, 1) = Anew(1, 4, 9, 1, 1) + A(i, j, k, 1, 1);
        end
    end
end
```

In the above for loop, `A(i, j, k, 1, 1)` is `B(1, 1)` at point `(i, j, k)` in the original domain. Could someone help me how I should approach in a *vectorize fashion*?

Comment: So for `cube6` in the first dimension it only has three elements, whereas other cubes in the same dimension has four? Aren't those cubes supposed to be of the same size?

Comment: @Divakar: please see my update in the question. All the cubes now have the save number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rows of `cube1,2,etc`can be given by `2*n-1:2*n+2` where n is the row number. this will be stored as an anonymous function to simplify the later code...

```
ind = @(n) 2*n-1 : 2*n+2
```

Vectorising the loop in the question, for `point(ii,jj,kk)` the value of `B(ll,mm)` a possible solution is as follows:

```
sum(reshape(A(ind(ii),ind(jj),ind(kk),ll,mm),1,[]))
```

where the above code gets all required elements, reshapes into a column and then sums

---

To generate values for all `ii`,`jj`,`kk`,`ll`,`mm` combinations

```
sA=size(A);
nii=sA(1)/2-1; njj=sA(2)/2-1; nkk=sA(3)/2-1; nll=sA(4); nmm=sA(5) %Sizes for grid

[ii,jj,kk,ll,mm]=ndgrid(1:nii,1:njj,1:nkk,1:nll,1:nmm);  %Creates grid

Anew=arrayfun(@(ii,jj,kk,ll,mm)sum(reshape(A(ind(ii),ind(jj),ind(kk),ll,mm),...
      1,[])),ii,jj,kk,ll,mm);                            %Apply function to grid
```

Comment: Absolutely a creative, fast, and efficient way of solving the problem. Loved it!

Comment: This is an awesome use of anonymous function! `S0` is the place to learn! +1 of course

Comment: @Divakar: where is `S0`?

Comment: `S0` as in the [S]tack[O]verflow.